# Asp.Net Razor page handler not correctly calling methods C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms, razor

Whats up guys. I am in the process of building a WebApplication with asp.net. I have a handler called OnPostTest() That is firing when I post data from my form to the page Model. I would like then to pass this received data to some methods stored in other parts of the project for further processing, this is where my issue is happening. When the OnPostTest() Method is fired,it will not allow me to instantiate an instance of another class or call a method of another class. When it reaches this point in the function the app continues to load on the webpage but it does not call the method or pass the data,it simplies stops. I am Quite confused to as why this is happening. If someone could help me narrow this down I would be very appreciative ,Thanks!

Code for OnPostTest():

```
public void OnPostTest()
        {
            //Ensure the Data has been Correctly Entered into the form.
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                error = "The Data was not In the correct form,Please try again.";
                BfvEncryption bfv = new BfvEncryption();
                //return Page();

            }
            error = "Is this working";

            //return RedirectToPage("/Index", new { city = UserData.Address });
        }
```

The View:

```
@page
@model Produce_WebApp.userData
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "UserDataInput";
    @Model.error;
}

<h1>UserDataInput</h1>
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="test">
    <input type="text" asp-for="UserData.FirstName" placeholder="FirstName" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="UserData.Address" placeholder="Address" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="UserData.Age" placeholder="Age" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="UserData.Weight" placeholder="Weight" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="UserData.Height" placeholder="Height" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="UserData.WaterPerDay" placeholder="Water Per Day" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="UserData.Sleep" placeholder="Sleep" />
    <p>
        <h1>Career</h1>
    </p>
    <input type="text" asp-for="UserData.Salary" placeholder="Salary" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="UserData.Breaks" placeholder="Breaks" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="UserData.HoursPerDay" placeholder="Hours Worked Per Day" />

    <Button type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public EmptyResult OnPostTest()
        {
            //Ensure the Data has been Correctly Entered into the form.
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                error = "The Data was not In the correct form,Please try again.";
                BfvEncryption bfv = new BfvEncryption();
                return new EmptyResult();

            }
            error = "Is this working";
         return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [ASP .NET Core's Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) system? It injects an instance of a class in the constructor of your PageModel so that the instance (or a new instance) is available across page refreshes.

```
public class YourPageModel : PageModel
{
    public IBfvEncryption _bfvEncryption { get; set; }

    public YourPageModel(IBfvEncryption bfvEncryption)
    {
        _bfvEncryption = bfvEncryption;
    }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        // ... etc.
    }

    public void OnPostTest()
    {
        //Ensure the Data has been Correctly Entered into the form.
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            error = "The Data was not In the correct form,Please try again.";

            // _bfvEncryption is available to you here now.
            // return Page();
        }

        error = "Is this working";

        //return RedirectToPage("/Index", new { city = InputModel.Address });
    }
}
```